# Why my DLL is not loaded?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

there :
  I wrote two dll projects, one's name is Core.dll, the other is Network.dll.
And in the main( not Core and not Network ) project, I use a class pointer NetworkInterface*. Where NetworkInterface is a pure virtual class. After running the main project, I found that the Core.dll is loaded but the Network.dll is not loaded( The output window shows ). The main project dependents on Both Core and Network.

I'm not using function LoadLibrary().

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Chen

Comment: We need more information. Is this a C++ project on Win32? How have you established dependencies between your projects? Where is `Main` defined if not in Core or Network?

Comment: Surely there are more appropriate tags than just "dll"; and perhaps some relevant code or linkage details?

Comment: Are you sure you called some function from Network.dll? Maybe you have some inlined functions in the header?

Comment: What does dependency walker show for your main application? How are you telling whether a dll was loaded or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If NetworkInterface is a pure virtual class then by definition it has not specified any object code to link with. If your main program does not use any code in network.dll, then it will not bother to link with it and will not load it at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

What ZDan said.

You need to export a "factory function" from the DLL that will return an instance of NetworkInterface.

```
__declspec(dllexport) NetworkInterface* CreateNetworkInterface()
{
     MyClassDerivedFromNetworkInterface *pNI = new MyClassDerivedFromNetworkInterface();
     return pNI;
}
```

Then in "main" somewhere, just say:

```
NetworkInterface *pNI = CreateNetworkInterface();
```

All of this presumes that you are linking to the network.lib stub library that gets built when you compile that DLL.